# how to properly use a web link as a raw_input in python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am writing a small class assignment in python. The raw_input suppose to be a link like 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_243948.xml'. If this works, then I can parse some of the data. I am doing this assignment using pycharm as the IDE. When it prompts me to enter a location and I type or paste in the above link and hit enter, it just opens the linked page and does not go in to process the rest of the data. Is there a way to enter this link without having it pop up the linked page? Please help me. thanks.

Comment: This is awful... And it isn't even your fault. It is really easy to reproduce. I guess ending it with a space and using `.strip()` after `raw_input(...)` is the only real option here, unless there is something in the options of PyCharm to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Can you use `BeautifulSoup`? :P

Answer (score 2):

While Stack Overflow isn't a homework-answering site, I can provide pointers on documentation to look at:

- [`urllib2.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) will allow you to create a file like object which reads from a web address.
- The [ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial) will allow you to parse XMLs without 3rd-party libraries.

These two should provide enough examples to get you on your way.

If your problem is with PyCharm automatically redirecting URLs entered in the console (which is a problem I can't seem to reproduce), the easiest solution is to simply always use the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The same case as I encounter.

My solution is to write the input() with a non-whitespace Enter to escape of prompting to the URL.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that? I don't understand what you're saying.